# Unable to Bulk insert data using python pyodbc query

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

I'm struggling to insert data from .csv into SQL Server DB table. The following query works perfectly well when executed in SSMS:

```
BULK INSERT dbo.Technical_Indicators_Regime_Work_SP500_Constituents_Daily_New 
FROM 'C:\Users\krakowi\Desktop\S&P_Weights_FactSet_reformatted.csv' 
WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = ';')
```

I thought similar can be easily translated to the following code:

```
def load_csv(load_sql):
    '''
    This function will load table from csv file according to
    the load SQL statement through ODBC
    '''
    try:
        cnxn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                              'Server=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;'
                              'Database=test;'
                              'Trusted_Connection=yes;')
        cursor = cnxn.cursor()
        # Execute SQL Load Statement
        cursor.execute(load_sql)
        print('Loading table completed successfully.')
        cnxn.close()

    except Exception as e:
        print("Error: {}".format(str(e)))



# Execution
load_sql = "BULK INSERT dbo.Technical_Indicators_Regime_Work_SP500_Constituents_Daily_New FROM 'C:\\Users\\krakowi\\Desktop\\S&P_Weights_FactSet_reformatted.csv' WITH(FIELDTERMINATOR = ';')"

load_csv(load_sql)
```

But unfortunately nothing happens (no records inserted), although it says completed without any errors. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: is necesary to use BULK ?

Comment: I don't want to insert records one by one because it takes too long. Is there any other way to achieve this NOT using bulk?

Comment: but maybe you can use executemany(statement, arguments)

Comment: Try adding `cnxn.autocommit = True` immediately after connecting.

Comment: @GordThompson thank you, this is working!